# What is the fastest way to get "specific" combinations of different lists?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tree, combinations, nested-loops

My final goal is building a football squad (squad = 11 players)

And all these 11 players are connected to some others. To put it simply, you can just think it as **"neural network architecture with 11 nodes"**.

Now imagine that **I have a seperate list for each spot (node_area)**. GoalKeeper_List, LeftBack_List, CenterMid_List ... and so on.

Each list has 15 players. So a node area can only be filled by the corresponding 15 players.

**There is just this rule:** When a node has it's neighbours ready (meaning *IT'S* NEIGHBOURS are filled/not empty) then there is a function going... Function checks if that node is do well with it's neighbours. It either returns "OK", or "Not-OK".

If function returns "OK", then it's okay and I can continue adding players. **But if function ever returns "Not-OK", then that means this squad is not going to work.** Regardless of the other node statuses.

Remember that this function is going to run for every node, with parameters as its neighbours. But **it can only run when that node's neighbours are ready**.

So what I want is, given 11x15 players (11 seperate lists), I want my program to give me all possible squads. If there was no rule, it would be 15^11 possible squads. Which is 8.6~ trillion squads and impossible to compute. But with all those rules, it limits the options greatly. So when code runs it give results around 1-30000 usually. So it's very countable by computers. I know these numbers because I did many practices. But the problem is, my program runs so slow. It's because in my code I have 11 for loops inside each other. It's just grow like trees, and calculating all these stuff takes time. My code sometimes give results in 40 seconds, sometimes 10 minutes, and sometimes never... (even though there are some possible squads)

And I'm sure there must be a smarter way to work this code faster, I need a new approach to this problem.

Here is my code so you can have a better understanding whats going on:

```
let working_squads = []

let current_full_squad = []
for (gk of GK_List){


  for(cb1 of CB1_List){
    current_full_squad = [gk]


    for(cb2 of CB2_List){
      current_full_squad = [gk, cb1]

      let GK_status = get_player_status(gk, [cb1, cb2])
      if(GK_status === "Not-OK") continue


      for (lb of LB_List){
        current_full_squad = [gk, cb1, cb2]


        for (cm1 of CM1_List){
          current_full_squad = [gk, lb, cb1, cb2]

          let LB_status = get_player_status(lb, [cb1, cm1])
          if(LB_status === "Not-OK") continue


          for (cm2 of CM2_List){
            current_full_squad = [gk, lb, cb1, cb2, cm1]

            let CB1_status = get_player_status(cb1, [gk, cb2, lb, cm1, cm2])
            if(CB1_status === "Not-OK") continue


            for (cm3 of CM3_List){
              current_full_squad = [gk, lb, cb1, cb2, cm1, cm2] 


              for (rb of RB_List){
                current_full_squad = [gk, lb, cb1, cb2, cm1, cm2, cm3]

                let RB_status = get_player_status(rb, [cm3, cb2])
                if(RB_status === "Not-OK") continue

                let CB2_status = get_player_status(cb2, [gk, cb1, cm2, cm3, rb])
                if(CB2_status === "Not-OK") continue


                for (cam of CAM_List){
                  current_full_squad = [gk, lb, cb1, cb2, rb, cm1, cm2, cm3] 

                  let CM2_status = get_player_status(cm2, [cb1, cb2, cm1, cm3, cam])
                  if(CM2_status === "Not-OK") continue


                  for (st1 of ST1_List){     
                    current_full_squad = [gk, lb, cb1, cb2, rb, cm1, cm2, cm3, cam] 


                    let CM1_status = get_player_status(cm1, [lb, cb1, cm2, st1])
                    if(CM1_status === "Not-OK") continue


                    for (st2 of ST2_List){
                      current_full_squad = [gk, lb, cb1, cb2, rb, cm1, cm2, cm3, cam, st1] 

                      let CM3_status = get_player_status(cm3, [cb2, rb, cm2, st2])
                      if(CM3_status === "Not-OK") continue

                      let CAM_status = get_player_status(cam, [cm2, st1, st2])
                      if(CAM_status === "Not-OK") continue

                      let ST1_status = get_player_status(st1, [cm1, cam, st2])
                      if(ST1_status === "Not-OK") continue

                      let ST2_status = get_player_status(st2, [cm3, cam, st1])
                      if(ST2_status === "Not-OK") continue


                      current_full_squad = [gk, lb, cb1, cb2, rb, cm1, cm2, cm3, cam, st1, st2]

                      working_squads.push(current_full_squad) 


                    }                                       
                  }
                }
              }
            }                       
          }                    
        }
      }
    }                     
  }


}

console.log(working_squads.length.toString() + " squads found! Here are they...... ")
```

Comment: Here's a hint: Make a recursive function that gives all possible squads given a list of already accepted players and a list of all other players

Comment: @Flutterish What you mean by "accepted" players? Also I had some others guys too that adviced me to use recursive functions, but how can I implement recursive funcs here and even then do you think it will really improve the performance "enough"?

Comment: Say you are building a squad. There are [ A, B, C, D ] players to choose from. You let player A in. That means accepted players = [ A ] and remaining players = [ B, C, D ]. I don't know if it will improve performance, however it will be easier to optimize.

Comment: @Flutterish Okay, out of 15 players, I just started with the first option, A. And remember thats only a list for the first spot (lets say goalkeeper) So, then what?  there are still 15^10 squads including A. Although only a few are going to make it their way to "working_squads" . I'm not sure if I can use recursive functions here and once again I'm not sure if using that will really speed up process greatly...

Comment: I'll code it up for you, hold on

Comment: @Flutterish ok thanks for your effort man, I will check it out

Comment: Writing this recursively (using backtracking) shouldn't speed it up but it will be more elegant and is worth doing as a start. This problem is called a [constraint satisfaction problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem) and there are highly optimized solvers you can plug into.

Comment: @ggorlen I already did some research on CSP but I don't know what is "backtracking" exactly. Can you please eloborate more and tell me what should I do /learn to highly optimize this? Are you talking about making these 15-element lists smaller somehow? I'm looking for a solution for months yet I can't find something really helpful man...

Answer (score 0):

This method is not faster ( in theory ), but more elegant. It also returns varying sizes of the teams if one of the lists is completely rejected. If you want only the squads with a certain size, you will have to filter them out either after or in the function.

The approach is to recursively ask the same question: Given this team and a set of lists of other players, what are all the possible teams? The method itself asks of every player if they want to join and if the squad is okay with it, for every remaining player, but just one in a given list. If its okay, it adds it to the team and runs itself again with that team, except without the list of players it choose from.

```js
class Player {
    constructor ( name ) {
        this.name = name;
        this.wontPlayWith = [];
    }

    AddRejectedPlayers ( ...player ) {
        this.wontPlayWith.push( ...player );
        return this;
    }

    WillPlayWith ( player ) { // just an example, you can implement this any way you want.
        return !this.wontPlayWith.includes( player );
    }
}

class Squad {
    constructor ( players ) {
        this.players = [ ...players ];
    }

    static MakeAllPossibleSquads ( acceptedPlayers, remainingPlayerLists ) {
        let result = ( remainingPlayerLists.length == 0 ) ? [ new Squad( acceptedPlayers ) ] : [];
        remainingPlayerLists = [ ...remainingPlayerLists ]; // just so we don't destroy the input list

        while ( remainingPlayerLists.length != 0 ) {
            let nextList = remainingPlayerLists.pop();

            for ( let i = 0; i < nextList.length; i++ ) {
                let nextPlayer = nextList[ i ];

                if ( acceptedPlayers.every( x => x.WillPlayWith( nextPlayer ) && nextPlayer.WillPlayWith( x ) ) ) {
                    result.push( ...Squad.MakeAllPossibleSquads( [ acceptedPlayers, nextPlayer ], remainingPlayerLists ) );
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}

console.log( Squad.MakeAllPossibleSquads( [], yourListOfPlayerLists ) );
```

Comment: Man I'm little confused and I have questions. In this example you only created 11 players, in reality I have 11 lists that contains 15x players. And then for each player, you added some rejected_player list, I get that. That means this player won't play with these given list. If they are all together there, this player says "no, i wont play with you guys". But how did you know if that player is not going to play with them? You did this manually yourself, why?

Comment: Ah, I see, you want to select one player from each list. You can achieve that with this method if you reject all players from that list for each player in that list. Or make the input a list of lists and in the "select next player" loop try for each one in the list and cut out the list instead of the player. The way I implemented the `WillPlayWith` method is just an example. You can implement it any way you want.